# When I transform and filter the images they get superposed with each others

Tags: html, css

I found a code that increase the size of the images when you hover and the image hovered isn't croped by the others:
[tutorialrepublic.com](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-increase-image-size-on-mouse-hover-without-affecting-the-other-elements)

But when I also put this code:

```
img {
  transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

The image get bigger and are not grayed out when you hover but the image get superposed with each others.
Is there a way for it to work without the images being superposed with each others.

Comment: depending on your code you may be able to use this in the css for your div: 

display: flex;
justify-content: center;
this should make them move when it gets bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the images and change the `z-index` on hover so that image will overlap the others. Here is an example using variables:

```css
ul {
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   gap: 1rem;
}

img {
    --grayscale: 100%;
    --zindex: 1;
    --scale: 1;
    --radius: 0;

    inline-size: 125px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;

    transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
    filter: grayscale(var(--grayscale));
    transform: scale(var(--scale));
    box-shadow: 0 0 var(--radius) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    z-index: var(--zindex);
}

a:hover img {
    --grayscale: 0;
    --zindex: 2;
    --scale: 1.5;
    --radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?v=1" alt="...">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?v=2" alt="...">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?v=3" alt="...">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```